# Haskell: No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `==' In the expression: (b == c)

Tags: haskell

So, im on my first steps on haskell, and i was asked on class to define the "elem" function. This was my first idea:

```
elemento :: a -> [a] -> Bool
elemento b listab = foldl (||) False (map (esIgual b) listab)

esIgual :: a -> a -> Bool
esIgual b c = (b == c)
```

Wich results in

> elem (parcialito).hs:5:18:
>       No instance for (Eq a)
>         arising from a use of `=='
>       In the expression: (b == c)
>       In an equation for`esIgual': esIgual b c = (b == c)

I think it´s something related to b and c not being recognized as a "Eq a" type or something like that, but as i said, im on baby steps here yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`esIgual` currently promises to return a `Bool` for any two objects of the same type `a`, with no requirements at all on what type that is. But it uses `==` to do that, and `==` only works of `a` is an instance of `Eq`, the typeclass that lets you compare objects for equality. That requirement needs to be reflected in the type signature of `esIgual`, like:

```
esIgual :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Then that needs to propagate out to `elemento` as well:

```
elemento :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

Answer (score 6):

I won't get into an explanation of [type classes](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) (you should read some haskell tutorials to find out about that) but the basic idea is that, as you said, in order to use the function `==` on `b` and `c`, which are both of type `a`, you need some guarantee that there is an implementation of the `==` function for that type. In haskell we call that a "type constraint" and we write it as:

```
esIgual :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
esIgual b c = (b == c)
```

Note that you could have omitted the type annotation for `esIgual` and the compiler would have inferred it for you. Try to write only

```
esIgual b c = (b == c)
```

then load the file into GHCI and type:

```
:t esIgual
```

You will also need to add a constraint in `elemento` since it is using isIgual:

```
elemento :: Eq a => ...
```

Check this out: http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101 :) The first example is precisely about `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `esIgual` to require arguments of types from the typeclass `Eq`:

```
esIgual :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
esIgual b c = (b == c)
```

Otherwise there's no way for Haskell to apply the `==` operator to the arbitrary type `a`.

(Or, as Aegis points out, just skip the declaration altogether)